# How to implement a unique index on two columns in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table and I'm trying to add a unique index on two columns. Those columns are also indexed. So my question is if I just can remove the indexes who were just for one column or if I have to use all three indexes:

```
add_index "subscriptions", ["user_id"]
add_index "subscriptions", ["content_id"]
add_index "subscriptions", ["user_id"], ["content_id"], :unique => true
```

Comment: As a side note: If you are using MySQL it makes no sense to have your `used_id` and `content_id` in separate indexes if you're also having a unique index of both columns. This probably also applies to other DBs... Contrary to what you expect, it will have a negative impact on performance (especially insertions/updates).

Comment: How does this work with nil values? Is there any way to do this with nullable column and if so how would null be counted? I would like to have it allow where one of the values could be nil, and allow for multiple tuples of that, but as soon as the nullable column gets value I want the combination to be unique. Is this possible?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

```
add_index :subscriptions, [:user_id, :content_id], unique: true
```

Comment: There are alternative syntaxes as well:

    add_index :subscriptions, [:user_id, :content_id], :unique => true
    add_index :subscriptions, %w(user_id content_id), :unique => true

They're the same thing, just different syntax for specifying the columns.

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil `%w(user_id content_id)` in ruby just creates an array of strings, it's not special to rails. You can do the same with `"user_id content_id".split` which is still creating an array of strings. I am sure you know this, this comment is just so other readers don't relate this to rails incorrectly :)

Comment: What would be the syntax for this on table creation? <- found answer  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870961/validate-uniqueness-of-multiple-columns)

Comment: I am having weird problem after using this. Not able to run any new migration using rake db:migrate. Only able to run migration using version number rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20180411062714  one file at a time. I already had data on the table on which I did unique true on two column.

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil Well, actually they are not the same thing, `%w(user_id content_id)` is an Array of Strings. Which is the same as `['user_id', 'content_id']`. The different notation for Array of Symbols is `%i(user_id content_id)`, or as the OP wrote it `[:user_id, :content_id]`

Comment: I'm not so familiar with ActiveRecord concepts, so I'm wondering if anyone could answer a question about this for me.

Comment: @zigzag Open a new question if you want to ask a new question. Comment if you want to ask for clarification about an existing answer.