# how can I require uniqueness of a "full_name" method, with first_name and last_name in my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

Users are able to create students in my database. Right now I have model validations for the presence of first_name and last_name. I have a method in my Student model for full_name.

```
def full_name
"#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

I'm wondering what I have to do require uniqueness of full_name without limiting first or last names. I want to be able to have Tom Smith, Tom Wilson,Tom Clancy, but not an erroneous reentry of Tom Smith.

Comment: So from a design standpoint, are you sure you want to do this?  Not only will you not be able to have two Tom Smiths, but with active model validations every name change will require loading every other persons first and last name to do a string comparison with them.

Comment: Try adding unique index on both first_name & last_name columns - Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123610/how-to-implement-a-unique-index-on-two-columns-in-rails

Comment: Just a thought. There might legitimately be 2 Tom Smiths, or 3. Names aren't unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would do

```
validates_uniqueness_of :first_name, scope: :last_name
```

You need to add an ***unique index*** to the ***students*** table as well to avoid ***race conditions***.

```
add_index :students, [ :first_name, :last_name ], :unique => true
```

More info [**here**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of).

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: That works, thanks. When I re-enter a name in the form, I get an error  .."PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_students_on_first_name_and_last_name" DETAIL: Key (first_name, last_name)=(Tom, Smith) already exists. ... What can I put on my create action to re-render the form with the message " student could not be created", or something similar?

Comment: @JeremyWalters Try `validates_uniqueness_of :first_name, scope: :last_name, message: "student could not be created"`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
# student.rb
def full_name_uniqueness
     if Student.exists?(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
       errors.add :base, "#{full_name} already exists" #change error key and message as you need
     end
end
```

Now write a custom a validation
    #student.rb

```
validates :full_name_uniqueness
```

Comment: Probably you meant "if" instead of "unless"